# Book about a teen underwater fish farmer?

Tags: story-identification

It has a green cover with picture of a boy swimming next to a submarine. The fish farmer and his surface dwelling girlfriend go on an adventure.

Comment: Please read [How to write a good story-id question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and edit your question to provide as many details as you can.

Comment: When did you read it? Was it new? Can you remember any names? Plot points? Was there a struggle or anything? Was it in English?

Comment: Those overwater fish are terrifying

Comment: See also [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203795/98028) which was likely searching for the same book, but remembered more details

Answer (score 3):

The cover doesn't match up, but the plotline vaguely does for *[Dark Life](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7027735-dark-life)*.

[image: Book cover]

> In a future America where rising seas have claimed much of the land, leaving Topsiders to pack themselves in tiny stacked apartments, some people have taken to the ocean. These pioneers live on the ocean floor, farming the sea and sending crops to the government in exchange for their homesteads. This is where Ty Townsend has lived all his life. He was the first child to be born in the undersea community of Benthic Territory and he loves it there. But when outlaws threaten the safety of the settlers, Ty must do what he can to save the only home he's ever known. And when a Topsider girl appears, searching for her prospector brother, she'll join him on his quest and together they'll find that there are secrets being kept about the Dark Life.

Some of the other reviews mention two submarines. Gemma is found in one by Ty. And another is shark-shaped.